# Angular Material 2 Select Error Not Displaying Below Control

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Angular 4.4.4

Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.12

I have created a template driven form with the following `mat-select` element:

```
<mat-form-field class="add-task-full-width">
    <mat-select matInput
                [(ngModel)]="taskForCreation.areaId"
                id="areaControl"
                #areaControl="ngModel"
                name="areaControl"
                required
                (ngModelChange)="onAreaChanged($event)"
                placeholder="Area">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let area of areas" [value]="area.id">
            {{ area.description }}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-error *ngIf="areaControl.hasError('required')">
            Area is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

If I tab out of the field without selecting an item from the list, the control does turn red and become invalid, but the error message is displayed at the bottom of the list, not below the control. No matter what I try I cannot change this.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mat-error` element should be placed outside of the `mat-select` and inside the `mat-form-field`. Please take a look at the [form field features](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages) of the `MatSelect` for further information about how to use it inside form fields.